# Extract raw audio frames from OGG music file with Android NDK

Tags: ffmpeg, android-ndk, oggvorbis

In my Android app, I would like to be able to process audio on the fly from an OGG file by extracting audio samples, process them and redirect them to the audio output.

I know how to make the last 2 steps using Android NDK, but I don't know how to extract audio samples to get them in an array of floats or shorts.

I tried to make [this code](https://github.com/979451341/FFmpegOpenslES/blob/master/src/main/cpp/FFmpegMusic.cpp) work that, apparently, can extract raw audio samples on the fly.

The problem is: I don't manage to add FFMpeg in my project. I tried many tutorials (like [this one](https://hackernoon.com/android-ndk-my-experience-with-ffmpeg-93dd7e4b9269)), but it seems pretty difficult since I work on Windows. So after a while, I found [Prebuild FFMpeg for Android](https://github.com/Khang-NT/ffmpeg-binary-android), that seems interesting since it's available for armeabi-v7a, arm64-v8a, x86 and x86_64 architectures, but again, I don't understand how to add it in my project.

I also took a look at `libogg`, `libvorbis` and `vorbisfile`, but I have no idea how to add them in my project.

So, does anyone have a working example on how to extract audio samples from an OGG file on the fly?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Read [cmake guide for android](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/configure-cmake), especially `Add other prebuilt libraries` part.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I finally managed to proceed:

1. Here is a very detailed tutorial that explains clearly how to compile FFMpeg for Android (please take a close look at the comments): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2OGbamEjYhc
2. Then, here is a good tutorial that explains how to implement the FFMpeg library in an Android project (starting from "Integration of pre-built C/C++ libraries to an Android project"): https://proandroiddev.com/android-ndk-how-to-integrate-pre-built-libraries-in-case-of-the-ffmpeg-7ff24551a0f
3. Here is how I finally managed to extract audio samples from an audio file using FFMpeg: https://gist.github.com/mregnauld/2538d98308ad57eb75cfcd36aab5099a

For the step #2, you'll just have to make minor updates so you can target the following ABIs:

- armeabi-v7a
- arm64-v8a
- x86
- x86_64

Hope this helps.

Comment: There seem to be a few problems with the code you linked to. I'm trying to solve a similar problem, so I pasted it into my app to see what it does. There seem to be 
1) a few semicolons missing (easy to fix)
2) more importantly an unresolved reference to a variable `stream` that is not declared anywhere. Would you mind explaining what `stream` is supposed to be and where it comes from? Then I could run and anlyze your snippet, which might be the key to solve my problem. Thanks!

Comment: @michpohl: For your information: 1) You're right, I fixed it, and 2) `stream` is actually a variable declared in a FFMpegPlayer.h, like this: `AVStream *stream = NULL;`. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you. I have a hard time wrapping my head around getting FFMpeg to work for me, and your example might just be the mssing piece for me to understand it all. Thanks for the info about the `stream`!